# How to write to stdin of external process in Elixir

Tags: unix, erlang, pipe, elixir, mkfifo

Is it possible to write to stdin of external process In Elixir? Is NIF the only option right now?

The process that started from Elixir, blocks and wait for user input:

```
pid = spawn(fn ->
   System.cmd("sh", [
    Path.join([System.cwd, "sh", "wait_for_input"]),
   "Hello world"
  ])
end)
```

I would like to achieve something like that

```
IO.write pid, "Hello"
IO.write pid, "Hello again"
```

And this is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
while read data
do
  echo $data >> file_output.txt
done
```

Comment: Check out Ports: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Port.html. Specifically, `Port.open/2` and `Port.command/3`.

Comment: This seems related too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872909/erlang-read-stdin-write-stdout

Comment: @Stratus3D I'm looking for the opposite, to write into stdin.

Comment: @Dogbert when I run the command it sends the data, but I don't see it writes to stdin for the external process.

Comment: @LemmonMaxwell can you post a simplified version of the script you're executing with `sh`  and writing data to so I can reproduce the error? `Port.command` should work: `iex(1)> port = Port.open({:spawn, "sh"}, []); Port.command(port, "echo 1\n");
iex(2)> flush
{#Port<0.1348>, {:data, '1\n'}}`.

Comment: @Dogbert yes, I just added it, thanks

Comment: `Port.command` works for me with that. Did you make sure to add a trailing `\n` so that `sh` actually executes the command?

Comment: @Dogbert no, that was the problem. Thanks! Please copy it as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Port`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html) for this. Note that the `read` builtin of `sh` will only get data when a newline character is sent to `sh`, so you need to add that whenever you want the buffered data to be sent to `read`.

```
$ cat wait_for_input
while read data
do
  echo $data >> file_output.txt
done
$ iex
iex(1)> port = Port.open({:spawn, "sh wait_for_input"}, [])
#Port<0.1260>
iex(2)> Port.command port, "foo\n"
true
iex(3)> Port.command port, "bar\n"
true
iex(4)> Port.close(port)
true
$ cat file_output.txt
foo
bar
```